# Set quick doc duration in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, I can enable "Show quick doc on mouse move" so that when I hover my mouse on an item, it display its documentation (like in Eclipse):

[image]

However, this quick doc only displays for about 2 seconds then automatically disappears. How can I make it stay there and only disappear when I click somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is a bug of Android Studio: if you open logcat, when a new log line appears, the quick doc window will automatically disappear. I've filed a bug report.

Answer (score 7):

Bring you mouse cursor on any of the method/variable and press :

```
Ctrl+Q
```

For Mac Users:

```
Ctrl+J
```

Comment: I specifically need the on-hover method.

Comment: if you will keep your mouse circle on the javadoc box it wont disappear .

Answer (score 0):

I found [Android Issue 180447](http://This%20is%20probably%20an%20issue%20in%20IntelliJ.%20I%20see%20similar%20behavior%20(IntelliJ%20CE%2014.1.4).%20%20FYI:%20My%20(imperfect)%20workaround%20is%20to%20%22Hide%22%20the%20%22Android%22%20tab%20(which%20stops%20displaying%20the%20tab's%20contents,%20but%20keeps%20the%20tab).%20That%20causes%20the%20Quick%20Doc%20popups%20to%20stay%20around.%20(Clicking%20on%20the%20%22Android%22%20tab%20re-displays%20its%20contents.)) for this, which is still open. I added the following additional info as a comment to it:

> This is probably an issue in IntelliJ. I see similar behavior
>   (IntelliJ CE 14.1.4).
>
> FYI: My (imperfect) workaround is to "Hide" the "Android" tab (which
>   stops displaying the tab's contents, but keeps the tab). That causes
>   the Quick Doc popups to stay around. (Clicking on the "Android" tab
>   re-displays its contents.)